# How to do divide column values in SQL update?

Tags: sql

What is the correct syntax to do a SQL Update on a column and divide its values by 1 000 000?

Comment: OK, that's a valid question and everything but... upvoting it? A basic SQL UPDATE command? Really?

Comment: Well, I wasn't too sure about the SQL division (normally I do it via PHP, not SQL directly). Now I know it's the same thing (/) ;)

Comment: Hey @Adam, your question is OK. It is valid, as I said. I just don't see the point to whoever upvoted it, it's a simple simple concept. Don't get me wrong, your question is fine.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET column = column / 1000000
```

Comment: or `1e6` if that's available to you since it will reduce the chance of miscounting those zeros :-)

Comment: Also, you should beware of the difference between int division and float/double division

Comment: Didn't know you could specify numbers like that in SQL and I've been using SQL for a long time. Therefore, I wouldn't suggest doing that as most people will not know what `1e6` is! :) I just tried in sqlite and it works though. Is that part of the standard?

Comment: @Adrian Carneiro that was my case, then I used `FLOOR` func.